# Can I detect dom event from swf

Tags: javascript, actionscript, jsonp

I've been developing a swf with Adobe CS4.

My problem is the following:

```
<a href="#" onclick="jsonp_func();return false" >click</a>
var jsonp_func = function(){
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type = "text/javascript"; 
  script.src = "http://example.com/api?callback=jsonp_callback";
  document.body.appendChild(script);
};

function jsonp_callback(data){
   //I wanna take the data to swf
}
```

How to send the data to swf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [SetVariable](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/142/tn_14253.html#javascript) or [ExternalInterface](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/156/tn_15683.html)

Demo: http://oddhammer.com/tutorials/firefox_setvariable/

Comment: Thank you so much. BTW Can I call actionscript by using the functino SetVariable?

Comment: You can access your flash methods from javascript with ExternalInterface.addCallback().

Comment: Thanks a lot, I get all of that I wanna do